# return type of function based on argument value existence in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following function in `index.js` file:

```
function myFn(val) {
  if (val) {
    return val;
  }
  return console.log(val);
}
```

I have the following type declaration in `index.d.ts` file:

```
declare function myFn<T>(val?: T): (T | void);
```

But the problem is that if i pass no arguemnt then there is no case where the function can return any value other than `void` type.

I would like to do something like this:

```
declare function myFn<T>: (val?: T) => (val ? T : void);
```

How can i implement this best? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid syntax, but I am going to assume you meant this:

```
declare function myFn<T>(val?: T): (T | void);
```

The problem here is that `val` is absent, the type `T` is not knowable, so typescript infers it as `unknown`.

To fix it, you need to give your generic parameter a default value for the case when there is no argument. Now typescript knows exactly what to use when `val` is omitted and doesn't have to guess.

```
declare function myFn<T = void>(val?: T): T;

const iAmVoid: void = myFn()
const iAmString: string = myFn('a string')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=43&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsBPAMVQB4AVeAXngDcctgA+ACnqggH4AueSgEp+lANwBYAFBSweAM4Z4WAIIEAak2D9GzWoVKo2gmfMUqCAZQwwsqAOb8FN+3uJk2Acijwntux8EgA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to determine the return type of a function based on the arguments passed to it. For example:

```
function myFn<T>(): void
function myFn<T>(val: T): T
function myFn<T>(val?: T): T | void {
  if (val) {
    return val;
  }
  return console.log(val);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DEwB4AqA+ACgEoAuRANzhgBMAoUSWBFDbfA8gQwBsydTEOeuGjwkaTLkJduAfj4CciAD4Uq1RAG9aiRDGCIOPIlp27EAJwCmUEBaQyA3GYC+Z67fuIICAM5xuKwA6bjgAcyNuImc3IA)

Answer (score 1):

@Alex 's answer is correct, I was just writting these examples that shows the way to use generics in different ways to avoid messing up the return type:

```
declare function myFn<T=void>(val?:T ):T  ;
const tvoid = myFn() // <-- type is void 
const tsds = myFn("sds") // <-- type is "sds" and not string
const tstring:string = myFn("sds") // <-- type is string  
const tstring2 = myFn<string>("sds") // <-- type is string  
const tnumber = myFn<number>(3) // <-- type is number
const t3 = myFn(3) // <-- type is 3
```

AFAIC, I prefer `const tstring2 = myFn<string>("sds")` that I find more "elegant"

Comment: Type `"sds"` is _assignable_ to `string`, though. So the fact it's a more specific subtype of `string` _probably_ doesn't matter.